# IPC through windows clipboard using c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ipc

This is how you can get last text item from clipboard:

```
OpenClipboard(nullptr);

    HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

    char* pszText = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hData));

    std::string text;
    if (pszText != nullptr)
    {
        text.assign(pszText);
    }

    GlobalUnlock(hData);

    CloseClipboard();

    std::cout << text;
```

This is how you can set an text item from clipboard:

```
std::string source("text");
    if (OpenClipboard(nullptr))
    {
        HGLOBAL clipbuffer;
        char* buffer;
        EmptyClipboard();
        clipbuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, source.length() + 1);
        buffer = (char*)GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
        strcpy(buffer, source.c_str());
        GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, clipbuffer);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
```

But I don't know how to delete last text item from clipboard, I would like to be able to not let the user see that I am using the clipboard or change his clipboard so he cant paste last thing he copied...

How can I do this, delete an text item from windows clipboard using c++ ?

Comment: Set clipboard content to previous or to empty string?

Comment: The clipboard is probably the poorest way to realize IPC under Windows.

Comment: set clipboard content to previous, poor but simple and fast... I think

Comment: how you sync the process?

Comment: @ClaudiuHBann You don't own the clipboard, the user does. It would be *very* poor manners to hijack the clipboard for private IPC. That's on top of all the other technical reasons against it.

Comment: Not all clipboard formats are easy/possible to save and restore at will. There are literally a dozen+ better ways to exchange data between apps than using the clipboard

Comment: [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). Pick any **except** the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

This is the strangest way to pass text from one app to another! Sending e-mail also comes to mind.

There is a Windows-native way to do that: send a `WM_COPYDATA` message.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata for details.